# Spaceship with multiple races of creatures with a facsimile/copy machine to create doubles

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel close to the year 2000, but I am unsure when it was first published.

The novel begins with a human being who gets paid to use a facsimile/copy machine to make a double of himself on a spaceship.

The machine is activated, and the man comes out and sees that he is still on Earth. He collects his payment. The copy of himself comes out of the machine and sees that he has been put onto the spaceship. He is bitterly disappointed, because he is an exact copy of the human on Earth but now he is stuck on a spaceship traveling to a distant destination.

On the spaceship with the man are several different races of creatures who are part of the crew.

I believe that the facsimile/copy process is done several times in the novel.

At one point, one of the copies of the man attempts to sabotage the mission due to being slightly crazy.

Answer (score 7):

This may be [*Farthest Star*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3512) or one of the other novels in the "Cuckoo" series by Pohl and Williamson.

It's been a long time since I read them, but the elements of non-destructive/duplicative teleportation to a spaceship crewed by many species are definitely present.

The series consists of:

- *Farthest Star*
- *Wall Around a Star*
- *Doomship*
- *The Org's Egg*

Comment: Note:  not Wall Around a Star.  The copy-cloning does sound like the tachyon transmitters, but I literally read it last week and it doesn't match.  The main character didn't get paid, was sent to Cuckoo, not a ship, and did not take part in any sabotage.

Comment: It does fit with Farthest Star though ...

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for the helpful comments. It's been so long since I read it I couldn't remember which volume it was, or even if what I read was the shorter work 'Doomship'.

Comment: It definitely sounds like the "Farthest Star". I will be heading to my local used book store in the next few weeks to pick this novel up. Thank you.